:DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection'
peerconnection:setremotedescriptionfailedenter image description hereWhen inbound call hold I got this exception in Chrome browser ,but in Firefox its working fine
emit "peerconnection:setremotedescriptionfailed" [error:DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to apply the description for m= section with mid='audio': Failed to set SSL role for the transport
the session exception is WebRTC Error

setRemoteDescription() is called on the peerConnection object to set the remote description.

have you know this issue please contact me, thanks in Advance.
